# How To Have Multiple Divs On One Line With Even Spacing

Tags: html, css

Trying to get multiple divs on the same line with even spacing. So they nicely fit the whole container.

Here is what i have got so far. Tried to set margin right and left equal to the same on all the boxes, but it is still tricky to make it even and sometimes the final box will go on a new line.

HTML

```
     <div id="serviceBox"> 
    <div class="serviceBox1">
        <h2> Heading 1</h2>
        <p>Information</p>
    </div>
     <div class="serviceBox2">
        <h2>Heading 2</h2>
        <p> Information</p>
    </div>
    <div class="serviceBox3">
        <h2>Heading 3</h2>
        <p>Information</p>
     </div>
    <div class="serviceBox4">
        <h2>Heading 4</h2>
        <p>Information</p>
     </div>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
#serviceBox
{
    width:100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top:75px;
    height:250px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
.serviceBox1, .serviceBox2, .serviceBox3, .serviceBox4 {
    float:left;
    width:20%;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #bdbdbd;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #bdbdbd;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #bdbdbd;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #bdbdbd;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ruJ2R/3/

Comment: Are you always going to have exactly 4 boxes?

Comment: Yes i will only have 4 boxes on one line.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would suggest adding a new element inside each serviceBox, in this example the `div` with class *box*

**CSS:**

```
#serviceBox
{
    width:100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top:75px;
    height:250px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
.serviceBox1, .serviceBox2, .serviceBox3, .serviceBox4 {
    float:left;
    width:25%;
}

.box{
    height: 250px;
    background-color: white;
    border:1px solid #bdbdbd;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #bdbdbd;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #bdbdbd;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #bdbdbd;
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <div id="serviceBox"> 
    <div class="serviceBox1">
        <div class="box">
        <h2> Heading 1</h2>
        <p>Information</p>
        </div>
    </div>
     <div class="serviceBox2">
         <div class="box">
        <h2>Heading 2</h2>
        <p> Information</p>
         </div>
    </div>
    <div class="serviceBox3">
        <div class="box">
        <h2>Heading 3</h2>
        <p>Information</p>
        </div>
     </div>
    <div class="serviceBox4">
        <div class="box">
        <h2>Heading 4</h2>
        <p>Information</p>
        </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

This way the service boxes are nicely a quarter of the container and inside service box you can add the border and shading to the new *box* element

Comment: Yes they are all on one line, but there is no even spacing in between them. This is what i asked in the title.

Comment: Yes Andrew, that's what i wanted

Comment: KHAN, you just need to add a margin or padding to the box element, like in Andrews fiddle. Then the elements will be evenly spaced and you dont need to worry about if they still fit.

Comment: I see Opifexer, but using float method when i add margin to the box element it pops out of the container http://jsfiddle.net/ruJ2R/13/

Comment: In my code, add the margin to the new `div` element with class _box_, **not** to the serviceBox1,serviceBox2. You will see it does not affect the spacing.

Comment: It will, but you can adjust the height of the .box element to compensate.

Comment: Opifexer i did. Have a look http://jsfiddle.net/ruJ2R/13/. But like @Andrew Clody said changing the height, sorts it out.

Comment: I used 'content' as the class name for the boxes. Changed to 'box' since you're using 'content' for something else.

http://jsfiddle.net/ruJ2R/19/  I think is what you want.

Comment: Worth noting, since you've added .container and .content along with #servicebox, there's a much cleaner way to do this without all the nested DIVs. The scope of your question has changed a bit, and this no longer adjusts based on browser width.

Comment: I see, maybe i should have specified clearer in my OP. Have a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/ruJ2R/20/ you see how the boxes automatically change width occurding to what is inside them. I wanted the boxes to be a fixed width.

Comment: Ive used Opifexer float method and it has seemed to have done the trick in my case. Ty.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: because of the borders , either apply `box-sizing:border-box` to your style, or put your div with borders inside one more div.

There are at least 4 different ways of doing it.

- using float layout
- using display:table-cell
- using display:inline-block
- using absolute positioning

  ```
  .serviceBox {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    margin-right:4%;
    float:left;
    width:20%;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #bdbdbd;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #bdbdbd;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #bdbdbd;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #bdbdbd;

  }

  .serviceBox:first { margin-left:4%; }
  ```

see updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ruJ2R/14/)

Comment: You see how the first box? is all the way to the left in your method. I meant that i want the boxes to all be in the middle with equal spacing on both sides.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the boxes have a border, so giving them `width` and `margin` in percentages that sum to 100% don't work: each box has an extra 2 pixels from the border, pushing the last one off the row.  But you can solve this problem by giving them negative margins to compensate for the border:

```
width:25%;
margins:0 -1px;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
.serviceBox {

margin-left:4%;

float:left;
width:20%;
height: 250px;
background-color: white;
border: 1px solid #bdbdbd;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #bdbdbd;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #bdbdbd;
box-shadow: 0 0 10px #bdbdbd;
```

}